# How to delete a row from a HTML table with React?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, row, delete-row

I am trying to delete a row inside a HTML table using React. I have an onClick handler on a delete button inside the row I would like to delete, but how can I target that specfic row to delete? I pass along a `site` variable with an unique id attribute. Maybe that helps?

```js
// table component

export default function IndexPage() {
  const site = { id: 123 };
  const removeSite = async ({ id, e }) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  };
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Valles Caldera National Preserve</td>
          <button onClick={(e) => removeSite(site,e )}>Delete</button>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lake-x08ql?file=/pages/index.js) to a code sandbox.

Comment: What specific row do you want to delete? Please add more details and show what do you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to implement this will be to display using an Array and giving ids to individual row items ->

Your code will be something like this then ->

```
const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([
    { name: "Valles Caldera National Preserve", id: 1 },
    { name: "Tyler Morales", id: 2 },
  ]);

  const removeSite = async (id) => {
    setDataArray((data) => data.filter((dataEach) => dataEach.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        {dataArray.map((data) => (
          <tr key={data.id}>
            <td>{data.name}</td>
            <button onClick={(e) => removeSite(data.id)}>Delete</button>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, I'll assume you plan to map over the data to generate each row.

If you're using an API to fetch the data, you could leverage the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to fetch the data and set it to a state variable with the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to manage the visible rows, something like:

```
export default function IndexPage() {

  const [sites,setSites] = [];
  useEffect(()=>{
    // Fetch your data here and pass it to setSites to set state
    // For example, setState([{ id: 123,name:"Valles Caldera National Preserve" }]) 
  },[])

  const removeSite = async ({ id, e }) => {
    // Below we update state to be the original array, less the clicked row
    setSites(sites.filter(site =>site.name !== id));
  };
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        {map.sites((site) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{site.name}</td>
              <button onClick={(e) => removeSite(site.id, e)}>Delete</button>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: What does the `e` do in this scenario? I don't see where it is used.

Comment: You don't need it, I left it in based on original code. Could absolutely be removed, just represents the click event

Answer (score 1):

React best pattern for any update is using `state` variables. So if you need to update a table, you should use a state array variable to store data of rows of table, for example `tableRows`, and using `.map()` to create table rows from this variable. Now if you update this variable using for example `setTableRows([...newVariable])`, this will automatically update your table.

**UPDATE based on your update:**

Should update your code like this:

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  const [sites, setSites] = [{ id: 123,name:"Valles Caldera National Preserve" }];

  const removeSite = (id) => {
    // do more staff like deleting from database

    // you may need to iterate through new array, because direct updating of state array variables do not force to re-render because of some reasons.
    setSites([...sites.filter(site => site.name !== id)]);
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        {map.sites((site) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{site.name}</td>
              <button onClick={() => removeSite(site.id)}>Delete</button>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm still confused on why you added the `[...sites.filter etc.]`. Why do you need to spread sites? Can you point to documentation that can explain this because I was able to implement this without the spread operator.